# Scala debugging under IntelliJ is horribly slow

Tags: java, macos, scala, ide, intellij-idea

I'm currently tracing through a relatively small Scala program (Apache's Kafka) with IntelliJ 10.5.4, while at the same time running several other Java applications in another project.  While the Java applications are doing just fine, the Scala debugging is horribly slow, a simple "Make Project" will take easily 2 minutes, and even basic cursor keystrokes take up to a second each to reflect on the screen.

I've used IntelliJ before with as many as 6 applications running at the same time, under multiple projects, and it doesn't have any problems at all.  Hardware isn't an issue either, this is all running on a very recent Macbook Pro (256GB SSD, 8Gb RAM, quad-core i7), under Java 1.6.0_31.

Are there any tips/tricks to making Scala perform decently while debugging under IntelliJ?  Alternatively, what are people out there using for Scala debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

re: compile times, [do you have FSC enabled](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2011/10/05/real-fsc-support/)? This dramatically helps Scala compile times.

re: overall slowness, you probably need to [tweak your JVM settings](http://alexshabanov.com/2011/12/12/idea-vmoptions/). Scala can be more memory intensive, so you may have to increase your `-Xmx` value to spend less time garbage collecting. Or lower it, if it's too dramatically high. Or change the garbage collector. For reference, here are mine:

```
<key>VMOptions</key>
<string>-ea -Xverify:none -Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/boot.jar -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC </string>
<key>VMOptions.i386</key>
<string>-Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m</string>
<key>VMOptions.x86_64</key>
<string>-Xms128m -Xmx800m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m -XX:+UseCompressedOops</string>
```

## Actually figuring it out

You will probably have to do some profiling to find out what the performance problem actually is. The simplest thing to start with would be to open [Activity Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_Monitor) to see if memory is low, CPU utilization is high, or disk activity is high. This will at least give you a clue as to what's going on. You have an SSD, so disk I/O is probably not a problem.

You may need to profile IDEA itself, such as running it with [YourKit Java Profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/download/index.jsp). This could tell you something interesting, such as if IDEA is spending an excessive amount of time garbage collecting.

In general, though, Scala seems a bit more memory intensive than Java on IntelliJ. It's possible that you have `-Xmx` set too low, causing excessive garbage collections. Or maybe it's set too high, so that when it does garbage collect, you get a pauses in the app. Changing which collector your using may help with that, but with all the collectors there's a point of diminishing returns where setting `-Xmx` too high causes performance problems.

Comment: It seems FSC is the way to go, and I've tried enabling it under IntelliJ, but keep running into issues with it.  Still trying a few more things, and will try to fiddle with the memory options you have.

Comment: mjuarez - I had problems with older versions of the plugin, but haven't had any in quite a long time. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Try [latest Idea 11 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11.1+EAP) with [latest Scala plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+Nightly+Builds+for+IDEA+X). It works for me fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I accidentally put breakpoint in one of the List's methods. It made intellij super slow while debugging scala project but when I canceled the breakpoint intellij became normal again.

The list of breakpoints can be found by clicking ctrl+shift+F8.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse with http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html is working very well for me as of 2.0.1.

My stuff is maven based at the moment and the projects are combined Java and Scala.  I can debug across language boundaries without problems.